# How to use dynamic variable between regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have string which contains some date and some comma separated values like this

```
var a = "1,13,20160308,200500000012016,10,Pending,01-02-2016,1|#|1,13,20160418,200500000012016,10,Pending,08-03-2016,1|#|1,13,20160623,200500000012016,10,Pending,18-04-2016,1|#|1,13,20160803,200500000012016,10,Pending,23-06-2016,1|#|1,13,20160912,200500000012016,10,Pending,03-08-2016,1|#|1,13,20161022,200500000012016,10,Pending,12-09-2016,1|#|1,13,20161129,200500000012016,10,Pending,22-10-2016,1|#|1,13,20170110,200500000012016,10,Pending,29-11-2016,1|#|1,13,20170215,200500000012016,10,Pending,10-01-2017,1|#|15-02-2017 APPEARANCE"
```

**regular expression:** `/(.)*?01-02-2016(.)*?\|\#\|/igm`
By using this regular expression i can able to delete unnecessary part in string.

Now i want to change 03-08-3016 (date) dynamically. If i use 
var date = "01-02-2016"
var reg = `/(.)*?${date}(.)*?\|\#\|/igm`;

If you pring reg in console.log you will get like this below
`console.log(reg)` ----> **output**: '/(.)*?01-02-2016(.)*?|#|/igm'

Expected Final output will delete  upto 01-02-2016,1|#|

Comment: show how should look the final string after replacement/deleting

Comment: updated plz check it

Comment: mmhh i am guessing, why not use it like this `/(.)*?+${date}+(.)*?\|\#\|/igm` I am talking about string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```js
var regex="(.)*?01-02-2016(.)*?\\|\\#\\|";
var rx=new RegExp(regex,"igm");
console.log(rx);
//Then when do you want to change,
regex=regex.replace("01-02-2016","03-02-2016");
rx=new RegExp(regex,"igm");
console.log(rx);
```

JavaScript have 2 methods to make a Regular Expression.
1. write it in slashes //
2. Make from string using new RexExp(string);

If you make it from string, you can give the constraint(" global, incase, etc.") as the second parameter as i did in the above.
and also you have to double escape (\) the escape characters.

Comment: By using ES6 syntax of template binding we can append variable 
We can also do this 

    var date = "01-02-2016"; // or dynamic date from db
    var regex=`(.)*?${date}(.)*?\\|\\#\\|`;
    var rx=new RegExp(regex,"igm")
    var output = "asdf 01-02-2016,1|#| done".replace(rx, '');
    console.log(output)

Comment: Thanks for the info @Deepakrao and will update myself. Sharing will help to gain more knowledge. (y)